# How can I render the motion path of an object?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, path, motion-capture

I have an object moves based on key frames. I used the motion paths tab to calculate the path which shows on my scene. My camera is pointed straight down at this path but when I try to render, it only shows the object moving, not the path. Is there a way I can get blender to render the path? Thanks!